# UDP - Server C#

Tags: c#, udp, client-server

I have managed to create a chat program where two clients can send and receive messages from each other. I am trying to improve it so that instead of the clients sending it to each other, the message is first sent to a server and then the server sends it to the client.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Any ideas for _what_? What have you tried? What don't you understand?

Comment: Any ideas of how to create the server part?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scale up your app so that they can chat with each other then I would suggest you to have a look into [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc297274.aspx).

> Two types of P2P network exist: a pure network and a hybrid network. A pure P2P network has no concept of a client or a server; it has only nodes, which act in the capacity of both a server and a client, as needed. A hybrid P2P network, on the other hand, has a central server that keeps track of the various peers on the network. This server responds to requests from the peers for information only and does not store any data. The peers are responsible for hosting the information. For example, in a file-sharing P2P application, the files are stored by the peer, and the server is aware of the files that are stored at each peer.

A hybrid P2P network may suit you. Also have a look at [this](https://github.com/ptony82/brunet) P2P library written in c#.

Comment: Isn't there a simple way of incorporating a Server with two clients?

Comment: That can be done simply using C#..But if you want your application to support multiple clients you can use P2P instead of reinventing the wheel.